# Spark Parallelizing List of Strings to Write

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a dataframe `df`

```
col1, col2, date
  a1,   b1, 2020-04-01
  a2,   b2, 2020-04-02
  a3,   b3, 2020-04-03
```

I want to write each date into their own location in s3. I collect `date` as a `List[String]`
then loop through each value to filter the df and write out.

```
val dateStr = df.select(col(date)).distinct.collect().toList.map(x => x(0).toString)
dateStr.foreach { d =>
val dateModified = d.replaceAll("-","/")
inputDf
.filter(inputDf(incrementIdentifierCol) === d)
.write.parquet(s"s3://bucket/$dateModified")
}
```

Is there a way to parallelize `dateStr` to filter on the dataframe and write instead of going one by one?

I know I can do

```
df.partitionBy("date").write.parquet("s3://bucket/")
```

but I dont want the location to be `s3://bucket/date=2020-04-01`. I want it to be `s3://bucket/2020/04/01` hence why I collect and run a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Performing writing in a loop is not a best option due to spark will create a separate stage for each write operation. That means that in case of failure while writing it will be difficult to determin what data was loaded and what data was not loaded especially if it is some incremental data loading. So I suggest to do everything in one writing stage.

`partitionBy` method can take more that one partition name as parameter. Add three more columns (year, month, day) to the dataframe you want to write with `withColumn` method.

```
df
    .withColumn("year", lit("2020"))
    .withColumn("month", lit("06"))
    .withColumn("day", lit("19"))
    .write
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
    .parquet("s3://bucket/" )
```

Hardcoded year, month, day values can be replaced by values from `date` column.

Comment: wouldnt this produce `s3://bucket/year=2020/month=06/day=19`? i dont want the column names in the path